# In R, is the behavior of [[<- reliable when the character index is the zero length string ("")?

Tags: r, list, replace, assign

I am using R 3.5.1. The `help("[[<-")` says, in part:

> Neither empty (`""`) nor `NA` indices match any names, not even empty nor missing names.

However, I find, for example,

```
> list1 <- list()
> list1[[""]] <- 42L
> list1[[""]] <- "WHAT IS SIX TIMES SEVEN"
> list1
[[1]]
[1] 42

[[2]]
[1] "WHAT IS SIX TIMES SEVEN"
```

I am writing a function similar to

```
list.revised <- function(list1=list(), name="", value=NA) {
    list1[[name]] <- value
    list1 }
```

I want a uniform interface (with defaults different from those of `[[<-`) for assigning list items and, since the items will not necessarily have names, a default of `""` for `name` is convenient, *provided that the behavior of* `[[""]]<-` *is reliable* (e.g., will not be removed as a bug in the near future):

```
> list.revised(list.revised(list.revised(name="ROSE", value="A ROSE"), name="TULIP", value="A ROSE"), value="A ROSE")
$`ROSE`
[1] "A ROSE"

$TULIP
[1] "A ROSE"

[[3]]
[1] "A ROSE"
```

Additionally, where is this behavior documented (if it is)?

Comment: Base R is very stable, so the behavior is unlikely to change. Just the same, I wouldn't recommend relying on it, as it's not very readable code and feels decidedly hacky. Instead, don't set a default and use `missing` in the control flow, e.g. `if(missing(name)) append(list1, value) else {list1[[name]] <- value; list1}`

Comment: @alistaire +1 for a prompt solution that I can use. If your "not very readable" phrase applies to the original definition of `list.revised`, _because of the use of_ `[[""]]<-`, I disagree, _provided that the behavior of_ `[[""]]<-` _is reliable_, which is the whole premise. The question is about whether that premise holds true; and you have suggested that it may not. If I'm misunderstanding the target of your phrase, please clarify.

Comment: By "readable" I'm not referring to whether it's reliable, but whether other people reading the code can understand what it does without running it. If you survey some R users about what `some_list[[""]] <- foo` does, I suspect most (myself included before this question) would guess incorrectly.